# Where does multi-role variable goes in Ansible?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, nginx, certbot

There are multiple kind of variables in Ansible. And I find it overwhelming to wrap my head around them. Some of them are:

- The one we can write in roles//vars/main.yml
- The one we can write in the tasks file itself.
- Then there are group_vars.
- Then we have host_vars.
- There are also vars files.

**My use case is**... I have three roles. Namely nginx, jenkins and certbot. Thing common in all of them is the domain name. I decided to use a variable named {{ fqdn }} in all of those for sake of refactoring.

I am not able to decide on which version to use.

**What I want is**... ability to input the `fqdn` from command line when playbook is running. There should be default value which I can put somewhere in the repo.

Answer (score 3):

See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). You can see that the role's defaults represent the lowest precedence for variables and the extra variables, declared on the command-line, override everything. There are a plethora of options between these two options.

For testing, create the roles and the playbook below. For example

```sh
shell> tree roles/
roles/
├── certbot
│   ├── defaults
│   │   └── main.yml
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── jenkins
│   ├── defaults
│   │   └── main.yml
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── nginx
    ├── defaults
    │   └── main.yml
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml

9 directories, 6 files
```

There are only two files in each role. The files are identical in all roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/certbot/defaults/main.yml 
fqdn: "{{ fqdn_default|default('srv.example.com') }}"

shell> cat roles/certbot/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: fqdn
```

Then, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - certbot
    - jenkins
    - nginx
```

gives as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [certbot : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: srv.example.com

TASK [jenkins : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: srv.example.com

TASK [nginx : debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: srv.example.com
```

In this example, the default values of *fqdn* in all roles are the same. Of course, you can declare different default values for each role if you want to.

---

You can declare the variable on the command-line

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e fqdn=www.example.com

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [certbot : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: www.example.com

TASK [jenkins : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: www.example.com

TASK [nginx : debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: www.example.com
```

---

Moreover, in this example, you can also change the default value, e.g. in the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml 
fqdn_default: default.example.com
```

Then the playbook will use the value of *fqdn_default*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************

TASK [certbot : debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: default.example.com

TASK [jenkins : debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: default.example.com

TASK [nginx : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: default.example.com
```

---

Use [vars_prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#interactive-input-prompts) if you want to `input the fqdn from the command line when the playbook is running`. e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: fqdn
      prompt: What is the fqdn?
      private: no
  roles:
    - certbot
    - jenkins
    - nginx
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
What is the fqdn?: ww9.example.com

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************

TASK [certbot : debug] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: ww9.example.com

TASK [jenkins : debug] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: ww9.example.com

TASK [nginx : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  fqdn: ww9.example.com
```

Quoting from the [Note](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#interactive-input-prompts): "*Prompts for individual vars_prompt variables will be skipped for any variable that is already defined through the command line --extra-vars option,...*"